# What is box shape in ion beam drivers for ICF?

Tags: laser, fusion, laser-interaction

What is the meaning of box shape in the ion beam pulses?
i mean in plasma we say the ion beam irradiating the capsule is box shaped. what does it mean?

Comment: A little unclear, but I think you want to hit the capsule with a square shaped pulse with as little ramp up (or down) as possible.

Comment: @Jon Custer   yes. but i don't have any information about the shape and what does it show? the square shape means 3 pulses? or two pulses?

Comment: One big pulse with little rise time to smash the capsule and keep smashing.